# Python: Storing estimated coefficients from different regressions in a single matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the below code which goes through my dataframe (`df_main`) and runs one regression (applying
`sm.OLS()`) per each unique value of `project_x`. Thus, the number of regressions corresponds to the number of unique values in `project_x`.

**Question:** How can I store the estimated (exponentiated!) coefficients from all regressions that I ran in one single matrix with the below dimensions?

- Number of rows=number of unique `project_x` values
- Number of columns=number of regression coefficients estimated

The matrix would therefore have the unique `project_x` values as rows and the regression coefficients estimated as columns with the intersection of each being the corresponding estimated regression coefficient.

---

My code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

for x in df_main.project_x.unique():
    df_holder=df_main[df_main.project_x == x]
    X = df_holder.drop(['unneeded1', 'unneeded2','unneeded3'], axis=1)
    X['constant']=1 
    Y = df_holder['sales']

    eq=sm.OLS(y, X)
    results=eq.fit()
    
    exp_coefficients=np.exp(results.params)
    print(exp_coefficients)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store `exp_coefficients` in a list in your loop and then convert into a matrix

Optionally you can also put it into a dataframe, see code ralated to df_index, df_columns, etc

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

df_index = []
coef_mtr = [] # start with an empty list
for x in df_main.project_x.unique():

    ...    # the rest of your code here
    exp_coefficients=np.exp(results.params)
#   print(exp_coefficients)
    coef_mtr.append(exp_coefficients)
    df_index.append(x)

coef_mtr = np.array(coef_mtr)

# create a dataframe with this data
df_columns = [f'coef_{n}' for n in range(coef_mtr.shape[1])]
df_matrix=pd.DataFrame(data = coef_mtr, index = df_index, columns = df_columns)
```

Comment: This is fantastic and points me in the right direction. I converted the matrix to a pandas dataframe via `df_matrix=pd.DataFrame(coef_mtr)`. It has the desired dimensions but I'm struggling to figure out how to label the 'rows' and 'columns' with my unique values (`project_x`) for rows and labels for estimated coefficients for columns. Any ideas?

Comment: @StatsScared you are on the right track! you just need to add the index and column names. See the updated answer for one way of doing it